# Django db in visual studio 2015

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I try to django sync db inv  visual studio 2015.

See screenshot:

[image]

but then I get this errors:

```
Python interactive window. Type $help for a list of commands.
Executing manage.py syncdb
Unknown command: 'syncdb'
Type 'manage.py help' for usage.
The Python REPL process has exited
>>> python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\visualstudio_py_repl.py", line 654, in run_one_command
    self.execute_item()
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\visualstudio_py_repl.py", line 628, in execute_code_work_item
    code = compile(self.current_code, '<stdin>', 'single', self.code_flags)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python manage.py migrate
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\visualstudio_py_repl.py", line 654, in run_one_command
    self.execute_item()
  File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python Tools for Visual Studio\2.2\visualstudio_py_repl.py", line 628, in execute_code_work_item
    code = compile(self.current_code, '<stdin>', 'single', self.code_flags)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    manage.py migrate
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So I already have read that you have to fill in:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

But that also doens' t work.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running the commands from an interactive python window. You should run them from the Windows command (cmd)

Comment: ? What do you mean. That is direct in visual studio. Django Management console

Comment: What happens if you run these commands from the Windows console?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this. You need to open the Windows command line in the project's folder. The easiest way to do this is to open File Explorer and navigate to the folder containing the project (contains the "manage.py" file). Once there, click on the "File" menu option in the header bar and choose "Open Command Prompt". They using "manage.py migrate" should work.